# jQuery function that will change image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I've got the following code for my images using srcset.  I'd prefer to get away from srcset altogether.  I want this to process all images with a particular class.

```
<img src="images/Connect-Groups-600.jpg"
srcset="
images/Connect-Groups-600.jpg 600w,
images/Connect-Groups-1000.jpg 1000w, 
images/Connect-Groups-1920.jpg 1920w,
images/Connect-Groups-2880.jpg 2880w
" alt=""/>
```

Does anyone know of a solution using jquery that will take the  tag and change the location based on screen size.  I need this to work on mobile devices too.

ex:

- If screen is bigger than 1920w, it uses
  images/2880/Connect-Groups.jpg
- If screen is bigger than 1000w and
  1920w or less, it will pull images/1920/Connect-Groups.jpg
- If screen is between 601 and 1000 it will pull
  images/1000/Connect-Groups.jpg
- if screen is 600w or less, it pulls images/600/Connect-Groups.jpg

If the size detection fails, I want it to always pull the image in the  tag.

I need this to work no matter what the image is...I have no clue what to even search for to find a solution to do this.

***EDIT***

At the end of this, I want to be able to put in  on the page... the code will then pull the URL from the img tag, and append the correct size folder.

It will end up looking like  on the end user side.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ as well as the `$(document).ready()` first load execution. This will result in your images being loaded _after_ your document is loaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using that method would result in slow loads if the page is image heavy.  I'd prefer something that just changed the location of the image it is pulling from and the images already being resized and it pulling only the size it needs.  It would still have to load the full 2880 image on a small mobile device before a resize function could even take place.

Comment: I'm doing this to speed up page load.  A smaller image loads quicker than a really large image.  But I need the large images too for filling screen on larger screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, this method is **not** sustainable, I would **not** recommend using it for anything else, but it will help you solve this specific issue:

Given that your folder structure remains something like:

images/`<size>`/`<filename.ext>`

We can re-create a source based on this information:

```
function resize() {

  // First, we'll grab all the images on the page that can be changed:
  var img = document.querySelectorAll('img.resizable');

    for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        // Grab the image extension
        var src = img[i].src.split('/')

        if (window.innerWidth > 1920) {
            img[i].src = "/images/2880/" + src[src.length - 1]; // Add the file name and extension 
        } 
        else if (window.innerWidth > 1000 && window.innerWidth <= 1920) {
            img[i].src = "/images/1920/" + src[src.length - 1]; // Add the file name and extension 
        } 
        else if (window.innerWidth > 601 && window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
            img[i].src = "/images/1000/" + src[src.length - 1]; // Add the file name and extension 
        } 
        else if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
            img[i].src = "/images/600/" + src[src.length - 1]; // Add the file name and extension 
        }     
    }

}

resize(); // execute when document is loaded to insert manual images for the first time without resizing
```

And ofcourse, load the basic 600 width file as default.

Example in jQuery:

```
function resize() {

    var img = $('img.resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();

    img.each(function(index, element) {

        var name = element.src.split('/') // Split is a native javascript function, which 'splits' the string into an array with the components

        if(width <= 600) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/600/' + name[name.length - 1]) // This name[name.length -1] trick is being used to select the 'last value in the string' based on the length of the string.
        }
        else if(width <= 1000) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/1000/' + name[name.length - 1])
        }
        else if(width <= 1920) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/1920/' + name[name.length - 1])          
        }        
        else {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/2880/' + name[name.length - 1])          
        }

    })

}

resize();
```

Comment: is this using javascript or jQuery?  looks like javascript :/  Also, what do you mean by not sustainable?  Whats your concerns with this script?  Is there a better way?

Comment: 1.) It does not use jQuery, it is entirely vanilla 2.) It's bad practice. What if someone edits your code and finds no CSS use for 'resizable' and removes it?? What if your boss decides that you need another breakpoint? This code will isn't sustainable or robust in that matter. But then again, perhaps i'm just really sceptical. I just finished a couple months of 'scenario based coding' in which we had to create code that would be foolproof for nearly every user.

Comment: Or what if someone from the dev section suddenly has a 'Eureka!' moment and renames the images folder to 'img/' ?

Comment: I would love to have an answer that is totally foolproof...but, that would be too much to ask for on stack overflow.  What I do need is a baseline of jquery (just because I can kinda understand jQuery better than javascript), and something to start with.  I plan to continue working with the code and seeing what I can come up with.  I appreciate all of your comments on the other persons post as well.  Thank you for putting the op over rep.  I accidentally deleted my edit part in my original question I guess so he didn't understand the need for this not to be a specific image dependent.

Comment: Alright, let me convert it to jQuery, because this is actually a **proper** reason for using jQuery:

Comment: @KDJ Included a jQuery-based solution

Comment: Hey @roberrrt , check out this page.  I am modifying this code to add an array.  I added an javascript array, I'd prefer a working jQuery array.  Figured I'd get you on this one as well since you wrote the initial code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259051/setting-up-an-array-to-handle-size-conditions-can-someone-help-me-get-this-arr?noredirect=1#comment65854560_39259051

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much identical to Muhammad's answer but in jQuery. If you wanted to do by class just remove the '#' and add a '.'

```js
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  console.log($(window).innerWidth);
  if ($(window).innerWidth > 1920) {
    $("#imageid").src = "images/2880/Connect-Groups.jpg";
  } else if ($(window).innerWidth > 1000 && $(window).innerWidth <= 1920) {
    $("#imageid").src = "images/1920/Connect-Groups.jpg";
  } else if ($(window).innerWidth > 601 && $(window).innerWidth <= 1000) {
    $("#imageid").src = "images/1000/Connect-Groups.jpg";
  } else if ($(window).innerWidth <= 600) {
    $("#imageid").src = "images/600/Connect-Groups.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="imageid">
```

Comment: it can't use specific images because this is going site wide...So it needs to pull image url inside code...

Comment: Size array? What do you mean? The image source doesn't really have any relevance to what you need to be done. You already know what image folder you're trying to point to based on the if statements (> 1920, you access 2880/.., if its > 100 and <= 1920, you use the 1920/ folder..etc). You could set up key value relationships with the size folder and an image source, and just plug that in. Not sure what else you could mean. This is the correct way to handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: thats why i took the array out..I'll look into modifying later...but I don't need the actual link there....sorry, an edit someone made removed part of the description.

Comment: can you check out the edit I made..that will prob give you a better description of the end result.  I had something in my original question but either I removed it on accident or someone else removed it in an edit.  Thanks ahead of time for your help.  Once that edit is done, your code should do exactly what I need.  Same setup, just pulling img name and appending folder in the middle of it.

Comment: The image names appear to be the same? But what you're asking I don't think makes much sense, take a look at your edit:

the code will then pull the URL from the img tag, and append the correct size folder.

The img tag won't have the size of the window in it, so you would have to do this in a nested if else-if statement. You already know the size of the window, so you should know what folder you want based on that? let me know if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: look at Roberrrt's answer...that is doing what I need I think, but it is in javascript and I need it in jQuery.  Same setup as what you have, just need the folders added to the middle of the url like his.

Comment: Why would you need it in jQuery when it's perfectly capable in Javascript ;)?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken (and I may be)...if someone disables javascript, wouldn't jQuery still run?

Comment: You are, jQuery is a _javascript library_ which requires javascript to be ran. You can see it as an extension of Javascript. (in weird comparison, you can cut food fine with a knife, but jQuery is like a swiss pocket knife, in which you can also easily do other stuff that are harder with a regular knife.

Comment: For consistency you might want to use jQuery if you're using it every where else, but that's very minor. @Roberrrt 's solution is fine, you just said you wanted it in jQuery, so I did that (which is literally the same thing but in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

**[Modified]**
let this is your image tag

```
<img class="imageid" src="images/Connect-Groups-600.jpg">
```

then this is the js you are looking for hopefully

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imageid");
var sizes = ["images/2880/Connect-Groups.jpg","images/1920/Connect-Groups.jpg","images/1000/Connect-Groups.jpg","images/600/Connect-Groups.jpg"];
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
  if (window.innerWidth > 1920) {
    images[0].src = sizes[0];
  } else if (window.innerWidth > 1000 && window.innerWidth <= 1920) {
    images[0].src = sizes[1];
  } else if (window.innerWidth > 601 && window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
    images[0].src = sizes[2];
  } else if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    images[0].src = sizes[3];
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="imageid" src="images/Connect-Groups-600.jpg">
```

Comment: This is pure Javascript, you need to handle it in jquery yourself if you need it in so, because you didn't asked about jquery that's why i did in javascript.

Comment: Is there a way in javascript to do an array of sizes, and it pull from that array.  array(600,1000,1920,2880)?  Just curious.  I appreciate the answer and I will plug it in and test it.

Comment: also, it needs to be a class...no id...because I want this to be used site wide....if there a multiple images on the same page, then it would only be able to pull a single image.

Comment: is it better now??

Comment: Hey KDJ I have modified as you asked, is it helpful enough? Thanks

Comment: The other thing is I also stated that I wanted to use this site wide...so using a single image inside the code won't work..the code needs to pull any image used.

Comment: Didn't I given him right answer?? If he wants more issues to be fixed he should create new question instead,

Comment: "Didn't I given him right answer?" No. 1) You address to a single `img` only. 2) Your construction **`&& window.innerWidth <= 1920`** is redundant. If previous condition (`>1920`) fails then this part of condition is `true` automatically.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev both of your points are false, he asked for single `img` in his actual question, and secondly don't you see `&&` operator??

Comment: You're avoiding the 'has OP received the answer he is seeking?' over the 'I have carefully answered the exact wordings he stated. Also, your 'enthousiast' behavior makes me believe your intentions aren't answering him, but rather farm reputation of him.

Comment: Instead of giving him your useful answers, you people prefer to find mistakes of others :(

Comment: @Roberrrt , and look what are you trying to do here, are you helping him, I was asking him not you ppls, if he would like to remove my answer I would immediately do.

Comment: Why don't you give answer instead of commenting on my answer?>

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is bad Muhammad, i'm merely stating that your behavior could be interpreted as being pushy, and that your answer is correct for the scenario you're providing, but isn't helping the OP with his actual problem.