# Setting up an array to handle size conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got the following code.  I am working on an array.  I found a javascript array instructions..if this is wrong, I'd love help to find out if there is a jQuery version of this.

My issue comes into play when I am trying to implement an `if()` and `else if()` conditions to the array.  I am using `i` (variable) to count items in array.

It is saying that there is an issue on the line that reads `else if(width <= Sizes[i]) { $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + Sizes[i] + '/' + name[name.length - 1]) }`

Also, it appears that the array isn't working at all.  Its pulling the default image.

I am probably doing this wrong.  I am doing this trying to figure out how arrays work and implementing them into a code I already have.  Can someone please help solve this?  It isn't working.  The code works perfectly without the array, so it is something in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = resize;
  function resize() {
    var img = $('img.resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    var Sizes, sLength, i;
    img.each(function(index, element) {
      var name = element.src.split('/') // Split is a native javascript function, which 'splits' the string into an array with the components
      Sizes = [2880, 1920, 1000, 600];
      sLength = Sizes.length;
      for (i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          if (width <= Sizes[i]) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + Sizes[i] + '/' + name[name.length - 1])
          }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
          else if (width <= Sizes[i]) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + Sizes[i] + '/' + name[name.length - 1])
          }
        }
      } else {
        $(element).attr('src', 'images/2880/' + name[name.length - 1])
      }
    })
  }
  resize();
});
```

The actual script I am trying to convert

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {

    var img = $('img.resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();


    img.each(function(index, element) {

        var name = element.src.split('/') // Split is a native javascript function, which 'splits' the string into an array with the components

        if(width <= 600) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/600/' + name[name.length - 1]) // This name[name.length -1] trick is being used to select the 'last value in the string' based on the length of the string.
        }
        else if(width <= 1000) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/1000/' + name[name.length - 1])
        }
        else if(width <= 1920) {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/1920/' + name[name.length - 1])          
        }        
        else {
            $(element).attr('src', 'images/2880/' + name[name.length - 1])          
        }

    })

}

resize();

});
```

Comment: If you can't have a statement starting with `else if`.

Comment: You are referencing `Sizes` array using lowercase `s` at `sizes[i]`?

Comment: @AlexanderGriffin I am more familiar with jQuery than vanilla JS so I'd prefer a solid jquery solution

Comment: I fixed the caplization, but its still not working...thanks for that

Comment: @jcaron - that is part of the problem.  I am new to arrays so trying to figure this out.

Comment: Had you bothered to indent your code, you'd probably have noticed that the `else if` statement is rogue, it has no starting `if` condition, and had you bothered checking your console, you'd get the error `"Unexpected token else"`

Comment: I realize that @adeneo; however, the else if is required to fully implement the code the way I know it works.  that is part of my problem.

Comment: @KDJ, this has nothing to do with arrays. You have an `else if`inside the block of an `if` (i.e. with no preceding `if` at the same level).

Comment: The `else if` can't be required in that way, as it's completely invalid, and a syntax error ?

Comment: yeah.  I just posted the actual script I am trying to convert.  Any way that someone can help with a solution to get my array working?

Comment: I am just trying to implement the sizes as an array rather than all listed out individually in the code. I want the array to handle the size if/else if statements

Comment: Looks like what you really want is to use "@media queries", not JavaScript at all...

Comment: Nope...not at all.  I want to use jQuery for other reasons...  Don't want to populate images via media queries

Comment: Hey KDJ, "else if" is not correctly used inside for loop

Comment: I've got that and changed it to if.  still doesn't work.  The entire array doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: yes the entire code is not properly written, no logic at all

Comment: Hi KDJ, what seems to be your current problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit verbose and follows your array starting with the largest value which I used instead of hard coding that for the "largest" (last) conditional.  Remove the console logs prior to deployment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = resize;
  var sizes = [2880, 1920, 1000, 600];

  function resize() {
    console.log('si');
    var img = $('img.resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    img.each(function(index, element) {
      var name = element.src.split('/');
      name = name[name.length - 1];
      var setto = 0;
      for (var i = sizes.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(i,width,setto, sizes[i]);
        if (width <= sizes[i]) {
          setto = sizes[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      setto = width >= sizes[0] ? sizes[0] : setto;
      $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + setto + '/' + name);
    });
  }
  resize();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that simplifies matters by using `Array#filter` to select the appropriate width; the appropriate size will sit in the first position of the sizes array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = resize;
  resize();
});
function resize() {
  // use $.each to iterate over each element
  $('img.resizable').each(function(index, element) {   
    // get the image name directly
    var name = element.src.substring(element.src.lastIndexOf('/'));   

    // let's whittle down sizes to *only* those that fit our screen width
    var sizes = [600, 1000, 1920, 2880].filter(function(s){ 
      return window.innerWidth < s || s == 2880;
    });
    // update the image with whatever size is in the first position
    $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + sizes[0] + name);
  });
}
```

We can move the resize function definition outside of your on ready handler, to make it globally accessible.  We can dispense with use of `split` to just find whatever is after the last `/` (the image name).  And we can avoid using loops and if statements with `breaks`, which tend to be difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `Sizes` array using lowercase `s` at `sizes[i]`, where `sizes` is not defined

Comment: I fixed that...doesn't fix the script though.  Thanks for the feedback on this!

Comment: @KDJ _"doesn't fix the script though"_ What is expected result?

Comment: I just added the script that I know works without the array.  I am just trying to implement the sizes as an array rather than all listed out individually in the code.  I want the array to handle the size if/else if statements

Comment: but I want this in an all jQuery version as well

Comment: The version without using an array appears less difficult to interpret. If if works, what is usefulness of substituting array for working approach?

Comment: it is...basically I want all those sizes listed in an array.  And I want the script to automatically populate sizes based on array values

Comment: I plan on populating sizes from a database.  That is why I'd rather use an array.  There may be more sizes in future, and I want it easy to populate and manage

Comment: kinda hard because it uses images to populate content.  And uses images in multiple folders at that.

Comment: The actual image being loaded should not matter, the setting of the `src` of `<img>` should verify expected result. You should be able to define function called at `.each()` as a named function, then nest an `$.each()` call to call same function for with `Sizes` as parameter, using same pattern as current working approach.

Comment: @KDJ You can view the `src` of `<img>` being changed by inspecting element at devtools

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could solve your problem:

```js
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
  var img = $('img.resizable');
  var width = $(window).innerWidth();
  var Sizes, sLength, i;
  img.each(function (index, element) {
    var name = element.getAttribute('src').split('/') // Split is a native javascript function, which 'splits' the string into an array with the components
    Sizes = [2880, 1920, 1000, 600].sort((a, b) => {return a - b;});
    sLength = Sizes.length;
    for (i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
      if (width <= Sizes[i]) {
        $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + Sizes[i] + '/' + name.pop())
        console.log('New src for image N. ' + index + ' is: ' + $(element).attr('src'));
        break;
      }
    }
  });
});

$(function () {
  // simulate a resize on dom ready: for testing
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<img class="resizable" src="images/100/nameofimage1.png">
<img class="resizable" src="images/100/nameofimage2.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this probably:

```
sort_array_small_to_large(Sizes)

for (i = 0; i < Sizes.length; i++)
{
   if (width <= Sizes[i])
   {
      size = Sizes[i]
      break
   }
}
$(element).attr('src', 'images/' + size + '/' + name[name.length - 1])
```

Comment: Warning: I don't actually know anything about the language you are using.  I'm just providing the logic I believe you are looking for.

Comment: that only pulls the largest one...not the one that is best fit for the size of window.  For some reason, that is only pulling the 2880

Comment: Oh right, I forgot, you obviously need the Sizes array from smallest to largest..  someone posted an answer that's like this one with sorting in it, so there ya go.

Comment: Changed my answer so that it's logically sound.